# Disabling redirecting after customer login magento

Tags: magento, redirect, account, javascript

All I want is to let a customer stay on his current page when he logs in to his Magento account.

Yes I know about the Magento backend option (found in: System > Configuration > Customers > 
Customer Configuration > Login Options) but when I turn this setting to NO it still redirects a customer to his account dashboard after loggin in.

Is there really no simple way to let a customer stay on the same page from where he is logging in?

I know about the Magento connect Psycho extension or something :) but I just need a code to implement.

Tia

Comment: [this](http://pradhab.blogspot.com/2013/04/magento-redirect-after-login-not.html) worked for me in mini login in magento. Simple edit in template file

Answer (score 3):

You should set to `NO` on `System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Login Options`

and in your `login.phtml` files (both, `persistent/customer/form` and `customer/form` on your template folder) you must change the action of your `<form>` to:

```
    action="<?php echo str_replace('login', 'loginPost', $this->helper('customer')->getLoginUrl()) ?>"
```

OR

Try this FREE extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-redirect-after-login-5446.html

Answer (score 3):

Can add follow code in login form phtml file

```
$refererUrl = $this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl($refererUrl);
```

Comment: This Only works when admin session is loaded on same browser, Weird !

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this will somewhat depend on the Magento version. In 1.7, if you check the function mentioned by @Rajat (`loginPostRedirect`), you'll see that the option you mention will only prevent the customer ending up on the dashboard if there is a referer param in the query string. If you add that query parameter to the action of the login form, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there also a way to prevent me from customize core files in this mather?

Answer (score 0):

For redirection you will have have to make changes to your Customer Controller.
For making changes in your controller better option would be to override your controller.

You will have to make change in loginPostRedirect() function in controller.
Make your changes to this line
**$session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getAccountUrl());**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Right now I have this simple form:     <form action="http://xxx/customer/account/loginPost/" method="post">
<p>Email:</p><input type="text" name="login[username]" id="mini-login"/>
<p>Password:</p><input type="password" name="login[password]" id="mini-password"/>

<button type="submit" class="button"><span><span>Login</span></span></button>
    </form> Where should I put what? T.I.A.